# "More content" indicator for commit messages in git log --online?

Tags: git, github, git-log, git-format

If you view commit history in Github, eg, it will indicate using ellipsis which commit message have additional lines of content beyond their subject line:

[image: Github history]

When using:

```
git log --oneline
```

in the terminal, is there any way to get a similar "more content" indicator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--oneline` is a standard (and very handy) shortcut format, but for anything more specific, you can rely on `--pretty` and build your output.

Try this **pretty format** ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats))

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %d %s%<(1,trunc)% b%-"
```

- `%h` shows the short-form hash;
- `%d` shows the decorations (branches, tags, and `HEAD`);
- `%s` shows the subject;
- `%<(1,trunc)` truncates the body (`% b`) to `..` if there's one;
- `%-` removes unwanted empty lines that are appended as the result of truncating the body.

---

**Coloring**

If you don't want to lose the automatic coloring of `--oneline`, you can replicate the most part with `%C(<color>)` ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emC82308203em))

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(auto)%d %C(reset)%s%C(red)%<(1,trunc)% b%-"
```

---

**Alias**

Of course with such formats, since nobody wants to type that each time, it's nearly mandatory to make it an alias

```
git config --global alias.line 'git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(red)%d %C(reset)%s%C(red)%<(1,trunc)% b%-"'

# which combines well with most options
git line
git line -10
git line --all --graph
```

*(finally, you can also put the `-10` or any other value as a default in the shortcut, it'll be used unless you override it explicitly, very handy)*

Comment: Followup question: On the log lines that are being truncated, there is also an unintended newline after them.  See [this image](https://i.imgur.com/02wT6VJ.png).  I believe this is because it's taking the final characters (which include a newline) and then adding `...`.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Jonah No :-) That's the line git uses to draw the `--graph`. Just get rid of the parameter if you prefer a straight list.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Why does git adding the `...` make it also also draw a graph line?

Comment: What command did you type to obtain what you're showing in that screenshot?

Comment: My full alias definition is `l1 = log --all --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset) <(1,trunc)%b'`

Comment: Also note, I've tried using values of 2 and 3 for the `trunc` command as well, per the help docs that say 1 is problematic, but that didn't change the newline behavior we're discussing.

Comment: That's what I was talking about : you're asking for a `--graph` in that command. Get rid of it and the line you described will be gone. There's no link at all between it and the `...` at the end of line

Comment: It's not `--graph`.  If you do nothing but remove the `%<(1,trunc)%b` from the end of the command, the extra lines go away.  Also if you look at the image I posted, you'll see they exist only after the `...` entries.

Comment: @Jonah You can remove the unwanted blank line after the `...` by ending your format string with `%-`, e.g. `--format=format:' .......... %<(1,trunc)%b%-'`